# Regular arrangement of tcolorboxes on a beamer slide

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tcolorbox

I would like to have a regular arrangement of 4 identical tcolorboxes on a slide.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\tcbset{width=(\linewidth-5mm)/3, before=, after=\hfill}

 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For some reason the last box is slightly shifted to the left (see picture).

[image]

What is the reason for it and how can I correct it? I can add \hspace to shift the box, but that is not very handy. When using different sized boxes on different slides, or different number of rows (it always appears on the last row, independent on how many rows are used) I would each time have to manually figure out the space to add.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems that every `tcolorbox` is considered like a word. As they are all together forming a paragraph, they are distributed as any regular paragraph: words are spreaded trying to fill every line except the last one which just ends without spreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment can be done using the `tcbraster` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height,raster column skip=10mm]
\begin{tcolorbox} test \end{tcolorbox} \begin{tcolorbox} test \end{tcolorbox} \begin{tcolorbox} test \end{tcolorbox} \begin{tcolorbox} test \end{tcolorbox} \begin{tcolorbox} test \end{tcolorbox} \begin{tcolorbox} test \end{tcolorbox} 
\end{tcbraster}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Anyhow it would be interesting to know what variable causes the last box to move inwards. But in case this is not known, I will just use tcbraster.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ignasi ! Understanding the last row of tcolorboxes as last line of paragraph solves the issue. I just needed to add

```
{\parfillskip=0pt\par}
```

So the earlier example would now look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\tcbset{width=(\linewidth-5mm)/2, before=, after=\hfill}

 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{tcolorbox}
       test
 \end{tcolorbox}{\parfillskip=0pt\par}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And the output is exactly as it should be:

[image]